# Validate onchange filename from input field (plain javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

**HTML**

```
<form>
<input type="file" onchange="return validateSize()" id="uploadFile" accept="image/*">
<button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function validateSize() {
const file = document.querySelector('#uploadFile');
const file_name = file.value;
const extension = file_name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
const size = file.files[0].size;
const allowedFormats = ["jpg", "jpeg"];
if (((size/1024)/1024) > 4) {
    // works perfect
    alert("Please optimize your image to maximum 4MB!");
    file.value = "";
    return false;
}
else if (!(allowedFormats.indexOf(extension) > -1)) {
    // works perfect
    alert("Please save your image in JPG format!");
    file.value = "";
    return false;
}
else if ((/^[a-z0-9\s\,\.\-\_]{5,50}\.(?:jpg|jpeg)$/i.test(file_name)) ==  false) {
    // this IS NOT working
    alert("Filename can have only letters (a-z), numbers, spaces, dots, '-' and '_'!");
    file.value = "";
    return false;
}
}
```

The size validation WORKS.

The extension validation WORKS.

The filename validation NOT work.

I wish to have this regex condition:

```
/^[a-z0-9\s\,\.\-\_]{5,50}\.(?:jpg|jpeg)$/i
```

**And if the filename have other characters that aren't included in the regex to return the alert.**

*Thanks!*

PS: You can test the code here https://jsfiddle.net/jacob19/a3fLog6r/5/ and see if you'll find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing your checking against the file's name, but against a *Fake Path*, generally something like `"C:\fakepath\file_name.ext"`.

The File's name is accessible as the [`.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/name) property of the File object you get:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.onchange = function(e) {
  // grab the File object that has been selected by the user
  var file_object = input.files[0];
  // here you have the file's name
  var file_name = file_object.name;

  // now you can do your check
  if ((/^[a-z0-9\s\,\.\-\_]{5,50}\.(?:jpg|jpeg)$/i.test(file_name)) == false) {
    alert("Filename can have only letters (a-z), numbers, spaces, dots, '-' and '_'!");
    input.value = "";
  }
  console.log("for info, the input's value was ", input.value);
  console.log("while the file's name was ", file_name);
};
```

```html
<input type="file">
```

Comment: **Thank you!** This is the solution :). I've adapted to my needs, but works perfect if access only the filename `input.files[0]`, not the whole path.

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp need letters or digits and necessarily 'space', comma, dot, -, _
I think you meant this

```
   /[a-zA-Z0-9\s\,\.\-\_]{5,50}\.(?:jpg|jpeg)$/i
```

Comment: Not the `alert("Filename can have only letters (a-z), numbers, spaces, dots, '-' and '_'!");` is the problem. I'll customize it after will work...  The filename must have only a-z letters, 0-9 digits, spaces, commas, dots, hyphens and underlines. (the filename can combine in any order all of them, it is practically the most common filenames; i only wish to block upload for files with all kind of strange characters from Chinese, Vietnamese...)

Comment: Yes, i understand you, but your regular expression does not what you want. Symbols \s\,\.\-\_ are must unclude in [] for this. Try     /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\,\.\-\_]{5,50}\.(?:jpg|jpeg)$/i

Answer (score 0):

You've made a small mistake in your regular expression. This bit:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]\s\,\.\-\_
```

Means: any lowercase letter, any uppercase letter or any digit *followed by* a whitespace character, a comma, a period, a dash *and* an underscore.

The `[]` operator indicates a selection. You should move everything inside it.

The `A-Z` syntax is just shorthand for `ABCD...WXYZ`.

Change the expression part to:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\s\,\.\-\_]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression seems to be correct. Your missing to `return true` in the end of your function after all the conditioning. Try this:

```
function validateSize() {
const file = document.querySelector('#uploadFile');
const file_name = file.value;
const extension = file_name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
const size = file.files[0].size;
const allowedFormats = ["jpg", "jpeg"];
if (((size/1024)/1024) > 4) {
    // works perfect
    alert("Please optimize your image to maximum 4MB!");
    file.value = "";
    return false;
}
else if (!(allowedFormats.indexOf(extension) > -1)) {
    // works perfect
    alert("Please save your image in JPG format!");
    file.value = "";
    return false;
}
else if ((/[a-z0-9\s\,\.\-\_]{5,50}\.(?:jpg|jpeg)/i.test(file_name)) ==  false) {
    // this IS NOT working
    alert("Filename can have only letters (a-z), numbers, spaces, dots, '-' and '_'!");
    file.value = "";
    return false;
} else {
    // stuf to do if everything is good, rhen return true.
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: No, your solution is not working.  Try it here https://jsfiddle.net/jacob19/a3fLog6r/5/ and maybe you'll find a solution, because in the past 5 hours i struggled only with this problem. :)

Comment: No, no errors. But the validation isn't working as it should. You can upload any filename (with all kind of characters !@#$%^&*...). You can test yourself and modify the code as you wish in the https://jsfiddle.net/jacob19/a3fLog6r/5/

Comment: @Jacob19 I edited my answer check it out. Removing `^` and `$` make it work.

Comment: Have you tried to select an image file called for example `myimage#.jpg` and the validation returned the alert ? I tried and the validation allowed that name, doesn't return the alert message even after i removed `^ $`.

Answer (score 0):

After the feedback from **@Kaiido** here's my solution that works and accomplish these tasks:

1. Check the file size.
2. Validate the file name.
3. Validate the file extension.

The JS code is smaller and i test it with various file names and sizes.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#uploadFile');
input.onchange = function(e) {
if (((input.files[0].size/1024)/1024) > 4) {
 alert("Please optimize your file to maximum 4MB!");
 input.value = "";
}
else if ((/^[a-z0-9\s\,\.\-\_]{5,50}\.(?:jpg|jpeg)$/i.test(input.files[0].name)) == false) {
    //i tested for image file, but i'll use it for various extension,
    //so you can just add other extensions in this part of the regex code (?:jpg|jpeg|pdf|docx)
 alert("Filename between 5-50 characters (letters (a-z), numbers, spaces, dots, '-' and '_').");
 input.value = "";
}
};
```

```html
<form>
<input type="file" id="uploadFile">
</form>
```

PS: Never forget that this validation is in frontend (client side), so you must have a validation rule for backend too. :)

*Cheers!*